# JSON Schema: Using anyOf, oneOf, allOf within additionalProperties

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I am trying to validate an object that can have arbitrary keys whose values are either an object that looks like:

`{ "href": "some string" }`

OR an array containing object's matching the above.

Here is what I currently have and DOES NOT WORK:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
    "id": "https://turnstyle.io/schema/links.json",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": {
        "oneOf": [
            {
                "type": "object",
                "required": "href"
            },
            {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "required": "href"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}



Passing example:
{
    "customer": { "href": "/customer/1" },
    "products": [
        { "href": "/product/1" },
        { "href": "/product/2" }
    ]
}

Failing example:
{
    "customer": { "wrongKey": "/customer/1" },
    "products": "aString"
}
```

Is it possible, and if so what is the proper syntax?

My assumption is that this will not work because the passing schema(s) in `oneOf|anyOf|allOf` of `additionalProperties` must apply to ALL keys falling under `additionalProperties`.

Comment: "My assumption is that this will not work because the passing schema(s) in oneOf|anyOf|allOf of additionalProperties must apply to ALL keys falling under additionalProperties."

No, different keys can be valid according to different schemas inside oneOf. Also anyOf is more efficient in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"required" should be an array of the properties which are mandatory in [v4](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#required-properties).

Or "required": true (or false) as part of the property in v3.

Try this:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
    "id": "https://turnstyle.io/schema/links.json",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": {
        "oneOf": [
            {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "href": {"type": "string"}
                },
                "required": ["href"]
            },
            {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "href": {"type": "string"}
                    },
                    "required": ["href"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: this schema is missing the "required" keyword.  it would accept an empty object as value or array of empty objects.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky you are right about that. It's not completely clear if that was indeed an accepted input or not, but it seems not, so I updated the schema accordingly